# Driving, feeding and similar terms in electronics

Tags: driver, terminology, electronic-load

My technical background isn't very strong, and I often hear about one circuit "driving" another, or "feeding" it. Although, intuitively, I believe I understand the concept, I am not sure I would be able to put it into words with enough rigor, hence, I'd like to understand it better.

Since these terms are used almost everywhere in electronics, be it digital or analog, I am sure this post could prove to be a nice place to learn about these concepts for other beginners, too.

Also, how much are these hardware concepts related to their software counterparts, e.g. device software driver vs its hardware driver?

Comment: Driver has low impedance (ideally zero ohms), receiver input has high impedance (ideally infinite ohms / zero Siemens). Energy flows from driver to receiver. So we use the driver to carry meaningful signal information to a receiver.

Comment: Device software driver is a collection of software code related to a piece of hardware. Different meaning of the word 'driver'. A device driver typically sends and receives information from its hardware.

Comment: An electrical output drives or feeds an electrical input.

Comment: @MarkU: if a driver had (almost) zero impedance and a receiver (almost) infinite impedance it would be (almost) impossible to have *energy* flow because driver and receiver are (almost) maximally mismatched.

Comment: @Curd Good catch, that's true, especially for controlled impedance systems, where both driver and receiver should match (complex conjugate) characteristic impedance of the transmission line. So the receiver has to have some finite input impedance, otherwise it doesn't sample any of the energy. But usually the receiver should take as little as it needs.  Anyway I think the issue in the original question was about terminology, didn't mean to get sidetracked...

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, guys! So, the way I see it now, this terminology seems only to refer to the input <-> output relation between two subsequent circuits...